# Build fail for google-signin package in react-native?

Tags: ios, react-native, google-signin

I am trying to implement [react-native-google-sigin](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin/blob/master/ios-guide.md) package to my react-native Ios project . I have configured everything.
But now the problem if I include google framework to my project there is a pop an error and **As soon as I remove it.** **It works!!**
I really don't know why m getting build fail with the following error

[image]

Every time i include ios/GoogleSdk frameworks in my project.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved this:

1. rm -rf node_modules/ ios/

> (Copied my podfile to another location)

2. npm install & react-native upgrade

> (this will give me a error free start cause by react-native link)

3. cp my podfile inside ios/ Pod install
4. Followed the remaining steps from react-native-google-signin
5. Added the following to my login.js (iosCLientId and CLientId are different Id's)

   await GoogleSignin.configure({

   iosClientId: 'iosClientId',

   webClientId: 'webClientId',

   offlineAccess: false

   });
6. Open Xcode Clear and Build the project.

## Note: I would have easily removed the googlesdk(frameworks), links and library . But instead I choose to get get a fresh start. Hope this helps anyone

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why or how but I ran into this issue and after numerous cleans, DerivedData deletes etc., the solution that worked for me was to follow XCode's advice on upgrading to the recommended settings and **changing the iOS Deployment Target of RNGoogleSignIn project to 8.0**. I'm using XCode 9 if that helps.

Comment: I have done some digging and used many technique for it but the most helpful for me was to dump node and ios and rebuild the project